# Spring Data Rest FetchType

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a problem with Rest response when I use ManyToMany annotation.
Problem is this answer:

```
Problem accessing /json2/1. Reason:

    Server Error

Caused by:

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.Tomek.entity.User.roles, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.Tomek.entity.Role["users"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.Tomek.entity.User["roles"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.Tomek.entity.User.roles, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.Tomek.entity.Role["users"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.Tomek.entity.User["roles"])
```

Without ManyToMany annotation(like in the Model class Role) I response JSON format

```
[{"id":1,"name":"ROLE_USER"},{"id":2,"name":"ROLE_ADMIN"}]
```

RestController

```
@Controller
public class RestController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private BlogService blogService;

    @Autowired
    private RoleService roleService;

@RequestMapping("/json")
    public String JsonLink(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("result", blogService.findAll());
        return "json";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/json2/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody List<Role> ShowJson(@PathVariable int id) {
        Hibernate.initialize(roleService.findAll());
        List<Role> role = roleService.findAll();
        System.out.println(role.toString());
        return role;
    }
```

Model Role (comment @ManyToMany)

```
@Entity
@JsonAutoDetect
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    /*@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "roles")
    private List<User> users;

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }*/

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Role(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Role() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Role [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

Model User

```
@Entity
@JsonAutoDetect
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    private String password;

    private boolean enabled;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable
    private List<Role> roles;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<Blog> blogs;

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public List<Blog> getBlogs() {
        return blogs;
    }

    public void setBlogs(List<Blog> blogs) {
        this.blogs = blogs;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class RoleService {

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    public List<Role> findAll(){
        return roleRepository.findAll();
    }
```

JSP

```
<c:forEach items="${result}" var="item">
<a href="<spring:url value="/json2/${item.id}" />">json</a>

</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with serializing property roles of User entity. When you load your entity in RoleService and then return result to controller the hibernate session is ended. You are not able to load it outside hibernate session.

You cannot load these property eagerly too. Then there would be a chance to load large tree of objects.

In my opinion to solve your proplem you have to create 3 REST services and 3 normal service method which would load flat data structures:

1. /roles/{id} - it loads single role (without users property)
2. /roles/{id}/users - it loads all users that have role with given id (without roles property)
3. /users/{id}/roles - it loads roles for user with given id

Additionaly you have to annotate your collection properties (roles, users) with annotation @JsonIgnore to ignore them during serialization to json.